# Deploying bluespice-free in Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, persistent-volumes

According to [this source](https://hub.docker.com/r/bluespice/bluespice-free), I can store to `my/data/folder` by following:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 -v {/my/data/folder}:/data bluespice/bluespice-free
```

I have created following deployment but not sure how to use persistent volume.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: bluespice
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: bluespice
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: bluespice
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: bluespice
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: bluespice
        image: bluespice/bluespice-free
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        env:
        - name: bs_url
          value: "https://bluespice.mycompany.local"
```

My persistent volume claim name is `bluespice-pvc`.

Also I have deployed the pod without persistent volume. Can I attach persistent volume on the fly to keep data?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to mount a local directory, you don't have to deal with PVC since [you can't force a specific host path in a PersistentVolumeClaim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63749652/16860542). For testing locally, you can use **hostPath** as it explained in the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath):

> A `hostPath` volume mounts a file or directory from the host node's filesystem into your Pod. This is not something that most Pods will need, but it offers a powerful escape hatch for some applications.
> For example, some uses for a  `hostPath`  are:
>
> - running a container that needs access to Docker internals; use a  `hostPath`  of  `/var/lib/docker`
> - running cAdvisor in a container; use a  `hostPath`  of  `/sys`
> - allowing a Pod to specify whether a given  `hostPath`  should exist prior to the Pod running, whether it should be created, and what it should exist as
>   In addition to the required  `path`  property, you can optionally specify a  `type`  for a  `hostPath`  volume.

##### hostPath configuration example:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: bluespice
  namespace: default
  labels:
      app: bluespice
spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
        matchLabels:
            app: bluespice
    template:
        metadata:
            labels:
                app: bluespice
        spec:
            containers:
            - image: bluespice/bluespice-free
            name: bluespice
            volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /data
              name: bluespice-volume
  volumes:
  - name: bluespice-volume
    hostPath:
      # directory location on host
      path: /my/data/folder
      # this field is optional
      type: Directory
```

However, if you want to move to a production cluster, you should consider more reliable option since allowing HostPaths has a lack of security and it's not portable:

> HostPath volumes present many security risks, and it is a best practice to avoid the use of HostPaths when possible. When a HostPath volume must be used, it should be scoped to only the required file or directory, and mounted as ReadOnly.
> If restricting HostPath access to specific directories through AdmissionPolicy,  `volumeMounts`  MUST be required to use  `readOnly`  mounts for the policy to be effective.

For more information about PersistentVolumes, you can check the [official Kubernetes documents](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/)

> A *PersistentVolume* (PV) is a piece of storage in the cluster that has been provisioned by an administrator or dynamically provisioned using [Storage Classes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/). It is a resource in the cluster just like a node is a cluster resource. PVs are volume plugins like Volumes, but have a lifecycle independent of any individual Pod that uses the PV. This API object captures the details of the implementation of the storage, be that NFS, iSCSI, or a cloud-provider-specific storage system.

> A *PersistentVolumeClaim* (PVC) is a request for storage by a user. It is similar to a Pod. Pods consume node resources and PVCs consume PV resources. Pods can request specific levels of resources (CPU and Memory). Claims can request specific size and access modes (e.g., they can be mounted ReadWriteOnce, ReadOnlyMany or ReadWriteMany, see [AccessModes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes)).

Therefore,  I would recommend to use some cloud solutions like GCP or AWS, or at least by using a NFS share directly from Kubernetes.  Also check this topic on [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56704413/16860542).

About your last question: [it's impossible to attach Persistent Volume on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43486870/16860542).